# Local web application as a captive portal with out authentication?

Tags: routing, wireless

We are on the final developing stages of an in browser mobile app (webApp) which will run in a non internet environment (underwater submarine). We are running a local server inside the submarine (windows 8 laptop with node.js), the app runs in node.js. We have a wireless router through which the server and clients connect, the server is assigned a static IP address (reserved IP address linked to it's mac address) all other connections are handled by DHCP with in an IP range. Right now we can access the app from mobile devices through the browser by typing in the IP address of the server, what we want to accomplish is to have a captive portal that every time a device is connected to the wireless network, the browser will automatically redirects it to the servers ip address, we don't what users to have to type an IP address on they're browsers. We now have a Linksys router with CoovaAp firmware but are not sure how to proceed.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: There's a load of [captive portal](http://serverfault.com/search?q=captive+portal) questions over on SF. But I'm not 100% sure this is off-topic here, so I've not pressed the close button.

Comment: This seems to be more about a single server configuration (application layer) rather than a network design problem. Therefore, I would second the notion that it would be more appropriate for ServerFault.

Comment: Thanks guys, thanks for your comments, I'll post my question over on SF.